# Presenting UIImagePickerController in camera mode causes crash in iOS 7

Tags: ios, iphone

At the time of presenting UIImagePickerController in camera mode using the code below, Xcode 5 memory view shows that my app consumes about 20 MB. When I present the controller, I receive memory warning in the overrode didReceiveMemoryWarning. But even without a chance to release any resources in there, the app just crashes without leaving any log messages. I am running the code in an iPhone 4S. I see other similar questions but the symptoms are slightly different than mine and I don't see any clear answers that led to resolving my issue. The same code does not cause a problem in iOS 6 or when I present the controller in photo library mode. My specific questions are:

1. Would it be normal to get memory warning with about 20 MB memory usage when presenting UIImagePickerController in camera mode?
2. Should I deal with this problem by reducing the memory consumption level further before I present the UIImagePickerController?

===

```
- (IBAction)cameraClicked:(id)sender
{
    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    imagePicker.navigationBarHidden = YES;
    imagePicker.toolbarHidden = YES;
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;

    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;  
    [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the error you are getting is it ? EXC_BAD_ACCESS
Try to debug with NSZombieEnabled available in instruments and also Symbolic and exceptional breakpoints so that you can trace the reason for the crash.

Comment: I set a break point in didReceiveMemoryWarning. It reached there but couldn't trace further since the app has crashed already at that time. Xcode shows message box: "[My app] exited unexpectedly. lost connection"

Comment: Try to reset the simulator and settings and empty the cached memory.It might help.

Comment: I made a clean build and it helped a bit. i.e. now it's not crashing at the time of presenting the UIImagePickerController but when I clicked the button that takes the picture. Xcode message box: "[My app] exited unexpectedly. Terminated due to Memory Pressure". The app crashed before reaching - imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo and Xcode couldn't show any footprints on the crash except the message box.

Comment: This seems to me as memory issue your device is running out of memory hence your application is not running and crashing unexpectedly try to free some memory and check with the instruments memory leakage and allocations this might help.Please let me know if i can help more.

Comment: Can check the link for your reference : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264304/severe-memory-problems-with-uiimagepickercontroller-using-camera?rq=1